# Why would the action not be able to connect to target class NSViewController?

Tags: swift, nsbutton

I'm trying to learn Swift, but I seem to have gotten stuck at this (admittedly, probably very simple) problem - the error as follows:

```
Could not connect action, target class NSViewController does not respond to -(encbutton/decbutton)
```

Here is my code. I'm designing my interface in the Storyboard and connecting it to the code through `@IB(Outlet/Action)`.

```
// ViewController.swift
import Cocoa
import Foundation

class TabViewController: NSTabViewController {
// This has been changed from NSViewController to NSTabViewController as I have replaced the initial single-view with a two-tab-view.

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

}

public class EncViewController: NSViewController {
    // This is for the first tab, encrypt

    @IBOutlet var encdirfield: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet var encpassfield: NSSecureTextField!
    @IBOutlet var enclogfield: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet var encbutton: NSButton!

    @IBAction func startenc(sender: NSButton) { // here's the problem. the function isn't triggered when the button is pressed
        // get values
        encdir = encdirfield.stringValue
        encpass = encpassfield.stringValue

        tarcrypt.enc();
        // this is an function that leads to an NSTask that runs a binary I wrote (not related).
        // definitely not the cause of the problem because running it independently works fine
    }


}

public class DecViewController: NSViewController {
    // and this is for the second tab, decrypt      

    @IBOutlet var decdirfield: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet var decpassfield: NSSecureTextField!
    @IBOutlet var declogfield: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet var decbutton: NSButton!
    @IBAction func startdec(sender: NSButton) { // here's the same problem, again. the function isn't triggered when the button is pressed
        // get values
        encdir = encdirfield.stringValue
        encpass = encpassfield.stringValue

        tarcrypt.dec();
        // this is an function that leads to an NSTask that runs a binary I wrote (not related).
        // definitely not the cause of the problem because running it independently works fine
    }

}
```

For some reason, upon drawing the scene along with the NSButton, the error message as seen above is generated. What is causing the error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I had the same issue but none of the answers work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out! For anyone else who runs into this problem, here's how to fix it:

It turns out there is a little dropdown under "Custom Class" titled "Module", which is, by default, set to none. Set it to `tarcrypt` (or whichever available option suits you) and that should fix the errors.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: That might be the most ridiculously frustrating bug I've come across. Does anyone know why this happens? I don't see it in other projects I've built.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you connected your UI element to the File's Owner object, which is an instance of NSApplication.

If you haven't done so already, you want to drag a NSObject out of the Object Library palette in Xcode 4 to the margin to the left of your layout. Once you've done that, and have selected it, choose the identity inspector and, in the Class field, enter "WindowController"

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5 and Xcode 13.3

Recently I had the same bug. I solved it by reassigning the viewcontroller class name to the class in my *nameclass.swift* file and activating the MODULE entry with my project name (following the dropdown menu).